# SQL MERGE error?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Please see my below code - I am new to SQL and haven't seen this error before. Can someone advise as to where it is going wrong? The error I am getting is

> (41669 row(s) affected) Msg 8672, Level 16, State 1, Line 41 The MERGE
>   statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once.
>   This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A
>   MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table
>   multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at
>   most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source
>   rows.

My code is below

```
DECLARE @FromDate DateTime = '31 jan 2018'
DECLARE @ToDate DateTime = '28 Feb 2018'


DECLARE @FromDate_In DateTime = @FromDate
DECLARE @ToDate_In DateTime = @ToDate
DECLARE @DirectDebit_In INT = 0

/**************************/
/*     Agreement view     */
/**************************/

SELECT
    sag.[AgreementID]
    ,sca.CustomerID
    ,'Lost' AS [Type]
INTO #AgreementSet
FROM Money.dbo.[Fin_SS_TblAgreements] sag WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN Money.dbo.[Fin_SS_TblCustomersAgreements] [sca] WITH (NOLOCK) ON sca.DealID = sag.DealID AND sca.IsMasterCustomer = 1 AND sca.[SnapShot] = sag.[SnapShot]
INNER JOIN ( 
            SELECT 
                sps.DealID
            FROM Money.dbo.[Fin_SS_TblPaymentSchedule] sps WITH (NOLOCK, INDEX(IX_NC_Snapshot))
            WHERE sps.[SnapShot] = @FromDate_In
            GROUP BY sps.DealID
            ) sps ON sag.DealID = sps.DealID

WHERE sag.[SnapShot] = @FromDate_In
AND (sag.AgreementID IS NOT NULL)
AND ((sag.EndDate > sag.[SnapShot]) OR (sag.EndDate = sag.[SnapShot] AND sag.Autorenew = 1))
AND (sag.AgreementStartsOn <= sag.[SnapShot]) 
AND ( (@DirectDebit_In = 0 AND sag.ContractTypeID <> 3) OR (@DirectDebit_In = 1 AND sag.ContractTypeID = 3) OR (@DirectDebit_In = 3) )

DECLARE @MaxAgIDFrom INT 
SELECT @MaxAgIDFrom = MAX(AgreementID) FROM Money.dbo.[Fin_SS_TblAgreements] WHERE [SnapShot] = @FromDate_In

DECLARE @MaxCIDFrom INT 
SELECT @MaxCIDFrom = MAX(CustomerID) FROM #AgreementSet

MERGE INTO #AgreementSet L
   USING    (
            SELECT
                sag.[AgreementID]
                ,sca.CustomerID
                ,'New' AS [Type]
            FROM Money.dbo.[Fin_SS_TblAgreements] sag WITH (NOLOCK)
            INNER JOIN Money.dbo.[Fin_SS_TblCustomersAgreements] [sca] WITH (NOLOCK) ON sca.DealID = sag.DealID AND sca.IsMasterCustomer = 1 AND sca.[SnapShot] = sag.[SnapShot]
            INNER JOIN ( 
                        SELECT 
                            sps.DealID
                        FROM Money.dbo.[Fin_SS_TblPaymentSchedule] sps WITH (NOLOCK, INDEX(IX_NC_Snapshot))
                        WHERE sps.[SnapShot] = @ToDate_In
                        GROUP BY sps.DealID
                        ) sps ON sag.DealID = sps.DealID

            WHERE sag.[SnapShot] = @ToDate_In
            AND (sag.AgreementID IS NOT NULL)
            AND ((sag.EndDate > sag.[SnapShot]) OR (sag.EndDate = sag.[SnapShot] AND sag.Autorenew = 1))
            AND (sag.AgreementStartsOn <= sag.[SnapShot]) 
            AND ( (@DirectDebit_In = 0 AND sag.ContractTypeID <> 3) OR (@DirectDebit_In = 1 AND sag.ContractTypeID = 3) OR (@DirectDebit_In = 3) )
            )  N
      ON L.AgreementID = N.AgreementID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET [Type] =      
        CASE    WHEN L.CustomerID = n.CustomerID THEN 'B/F'
                ELSE 'Swap'
        END
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (AgreementID, CustomerID, [Type])
  VALUES (n.AgreementID, n.CustomerID, n.[Type])
```

Comment: Please don't destroy your post. The point of marking a question as duplciate but *leaving the content* is so that it can serve as a useful *signpost* for others with the same issue. I.e. you didn't find the duplicate when you initially searched the site. It's possible that future visitors will also fail to find the duplicate but may use similar words to the ones *you* used in this post and so find it first.

Answer (score 2):

We get this very often.

This happens because of unique column that is being used in more than one row.

In your case this may be because of same agreementid for two or more different customers.

Check the data again and perform the same operation again.